# Remove part of each string in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove a part of each string in an array?

For example, an array like:

```
["u_img/5/16.png", "u_img/5/17.png", "u_img/5/19.png", "u_img/5/18.png"]
```

With `u_img/5/` removed, the result:

```
["16.png", "17.png", "19.png", "18.png"]
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function should do what you want.

```js
let original = ["u_img/5/16.png", "u_img/5/17.png", "u_img/5/19.png", "u_img/5/18.png"],
  result = original.map(function(d) {
    return d.replace('u_img/5/', '');
  });
console.log(result); //["16.png", "17.png", "19.png", "18.png"]
```

Comment: i think sub string is better than string replace:
var fileNameIndex = d.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
return d.substr(fileNameIndex);

Comment: is it like var old_array = ["u_img/5/16.png", "u_img/5/17.png", "u_img/5/19.png", "u_img/5/18.png"];   var result = old_array.map(function(d) { return d.replace('u_img/5/', ''); });

Comment: Yes. I used the name "original" where you are using "old_array".

Comment: Using shorthand notation, `result = original.map(x=>x.replace('match','');`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use the `each` function (since you specified jquery in the tag):

```
var x = ["u_img/5/16.png", "u_img/5/17.png", "u_img/5/19.png", "u_img/5/18.png"];

$.each(x, function (index, value) {
    x[index] = value.replace("u_img/5/", "");
});

console.log(x);
```